# Usage of Google Maps in my application

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm forming an idea about an app, but because I'm just learning to code and to make apps I would like to ask you few questions, just so I know wether to develop my idea further or to start on something new.

I'm thinking of an app, that would interact with a map(possibly Google maps or some alternative), but the app would not require the location. The user would be able to look around the map and interact where possible(1.)In real time if possible??) with the changes other users made.

2. What is best to use in my case and is it extremely difficult to manage such data in an android application?
3. Is there an equal alternative to Google maps that I could use or is Google best provider of "services" I need?
4. Is there anything in Google maps terms of service that would not allow such usage of their maps?

Again sorry for my unprofessional terms and bad English, and thank you in advance for your answers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It depends on your data. Possible limitations are network usage and server quotas. To show data in near-realtime you will need to query your server at fixed time intervals, say once every 30 seconds. If your data is heavy enough, you could be wasting the user network usage. Some server providers, also, charge you based on how many queries you do.

I'd say that, with some limitations, it is possible.

2. Google Maps is OK in my opinion. You will only have to find a provider that offers server management and hosts data, or implement your own. You can take a look, for example, at parse.com .
3. There are alternatives to Google Maps, but it has no limitations for what you want to do. Showing maps is free and google maps are deeply integrated both with the framework and with the user habits.
4. No, in my opinion.

Comment: Thank you for such quick answer. I have plenty of learning to do and there is a lot of work to be done, but nevertheless i believe it will be worth it if nothing else I will learn a lot.